# Confusion about connecteddness

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topology $R^2$ with the euclidean metric. Consider the closed unit disc centred at the origin. Let $A$ be its closure with the origin removed. I am curious if this is a connected or disconnected topological subspace.

My thoughts: Clearly it is path connected. So, since this is a metric space, one would think that it is topologically connected. However, I have an issue with that. One of the results in my notes is

[image]

Consider $f(x,y)=x$. This is a projection map and is hence continuous. However, cleary $f(X)$ is not an interval as
$$
f(X)= [-1,0) \cup (0,1]
$$

Something seems to be wrong.

Could someone help me figure out what is going on here?

Comment: What I mean to consturct is the closed unit disk with the origin removed. Apologies for the unclarity.

Comment: Any path connected space is connected, you don’t need to further assume the space is metric

Comment: $p=(0,\frac12)$ is in $A$.  $f(p)= 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(X) = [-1, 1]$ because, e.g., the point $(0, 1)$ maps to $0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh my god... My eye sight is getting worse. Thank you for pointing that out! Just a quick question, the theorem holds for subspaces right?

Comment: @MathsWizzard Connectivity is an ‘absolute’ property, like compactness. The subset is connected/compact iff the sub*space* is connected/compact.